# How can I query a string received with a request in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create an If-Statement for searching by name.

If the user 'John Doe' wants to search for his name by just typing 'joh', then how do I write the code?

Below didn't worked.

```
public function search_by_name(Request $request) 
    { 
        if('%'.$request->name.'%' != Auth::user()->name) {
            Flash::error('Sorry, you are not Auth::user()->name');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    ...
```

Comment: You can use `strpos()` php function to search in string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this like,

```
   if (strpos($request->name, Auth::user()->name) !== false) {
        Flash::error('Sorry, you are not Auth::user()->name');
            return redirect()->back();
    }
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

See laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-is

```
if (!str_is('*' . $request->name . '*', Auth::user()->name)) {
    Flash::error('Sorry, you are not Auth::user()->name');    
    return redirect()->back();
}
```